# Drupal 7 Two users having same roles and permissions but showing different result

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

There are 2 users having same role and permissions as Super Admin, User A and User B. User A is default super admin from Drupal 7 and User B is created by me, assigned same role to him as Super Admin. On website it shows list of movies. When I create new movie, User A can see its entry in list of movies and can edit or delete it. But when I login using User B, User B can't see the new movie entry in the list. I am new to Drupal.

Comment: Movies is a "Content Type" of drupal, so go to people->permissions, search content type for example "movies" and anable edit,delete, ALSO for the new role that you added ( User B )

Comment: @Diego182 Yes, its a content type. Super Admin its the same role assigned to both the users

Comment: try to change the permission by the database! search the table where users have the permissions of role! and try to give superadmin permission to user B

Comment: @Diego182 Super Admin role already assigned to both the users

Comment: Just go on admin/people/permissions and check again permissions for your user B role for that content. From your statements i assume you did not go on that page. There you can change permissions for every role on every content type (you just keep repeating you assigned Admin role to user B which doesn't mean you must have full privileges for that role).

Comment: @Darko  On page admin/people/permissions User B's permissions are correct to the content...

Comment: There is 'access arguments' => array('edit any movie content')  but i could not file "edit any movie content" in permission page

Answer (score 0):

Master admin (the first admin created during drupal installation - has user id 1) has permissions to do anything on site no matter what role is assigned to him.

Comment: I have given same permissions of Super Admin to User B... Is there a caching problem that shoulb be taken care of?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that super admin has permissions to do anything regardless permissions you have to him.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I want him i.e User B to  work as Super Admin...but its not working. Some movie entries that user id 1 can see, are not visible to User B.  Role of B is Super admin

Comment: Anyway I like the name "Spoiled Milk" @game developer.

Comment: There is no "Super Admin" role in default drupal installation. So must be that developer created that role and assigned permissions to it. So check what permissions that role has.

Comment: I Renamed it to super admin earlier...but its default drupal admin with id 1

Answer (score 0):

Suber-admin(uid 1) have all access ,if any menu /link does not have any hook_perm() integration properly then it always accessible for uid 1 but ot or other.